# Nested Buttons (nested tabbable entities)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**Problem:**
React complains about nesting a `<button>` within a `<button>`

**Cause:**
Need to keyboard `<TAB>` to a parent and children of that parent.

**Example:**
 clicking on the parent selects it, but there are buttons within the entity as well

[image: a]

**Flawed Solution:**
Using an `<a href="#">` anchor tag for either the parent or the children... `href="#"` required because otherwise it is not tabbable.

**Caveat:**
This is not ideal because I don't care about the `#`, and it appears at the bottom of the page when hovering and tabbing.  A common practice is putting the method like `#selectAngry-1294363.png` but that's unneccessary too.

**Compromise:**
Though react spits out a warning, my browser doesn't seem to care about a button within a button, so it this even a problem?

**TL;DR:**
The two things I care about:

- Must be able to tab to parents and children
- Does not display a `#hash` when hovering, like normal links do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) it is not valid to put a button inside a button.

> Content model:
>
> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant and no descendant with the tabindex attribute specified.

Depending on the desired style of the button you want to create here are some options to do it

1. aligning two buttons or more next to each other in div
2. creating a div with one button, and then position the other buttons relative to that div ( i would go with this option based on the image you posted)

Now for tapping you have to handle that yourself, when the pop up is opened you have to trap focus inside it, you can use [focus-trap-react](https://github.com/davidtheclark/focus-trap-react) or some other library. and then using correct tab indexes inside the pop up itself will make things work out.

Comment: K, cool.  I think I will make the parent clickable, but I'll make the actual header text the button to focus to.  No border or background, but then they can tab to it.